# react-native flatlist item translate animation not rendering

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am new to React Native. I have an empty FlatList at the beginning and the items are appended dynamically. The append process has an animation that the item moves from the bottom of the screen. However, the item would not show until the item is approaching its final position of the FlatList. I think it is because the FlatList will not render the item until the new height is reached. I wonder how I can make the animation work without this limitation. [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You can design your custom animation or there are many animation libraries. If, you are using Expo than expo

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/animated here you will find animation.

You can find following resource useful

[react native animated flatlist item after item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177067/react-native-animated-flatlist-item-after-item)

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-animate-the-items-of-a-react-native-flatlist-32c8cbf7ea3d