# react native animated flatlist item after item

Tags: animation, react-native

I'm looking a way to make animated flatlist item after item. when one item finish his animation so next item(from the flatlist) will be on the screen

```
class AnimatedFlatList extends React.PureComponent {
    state = {selected: (new Map(): Map<string, boolean>)};
    let data = {[
        {"first_name":"ltorrejon0@si.edu"},
        {"first_name":"ichadbourne1@icq.com"},
        {"first_name":"ascorthorne2@mediafire.com"},
        {"first_name":"jlathwood3@xing.com"},
        {"first_name":"molkowicz4@ftc.gov"},
        {"first_name":"motridge5@tiny.cc"},
        {"first_name":"rcess6@hostgator.com"},
        {"first_name":"mmaundrell7@php.net"},
        {"first_name":"ufairburne8@instagram.com"},
        {"first_name":"pangel9@biglobe.ne.jp"}]
    };

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

    _onPressItem = (id: string) => {
        // updater functions are preferred for transactional updates
        this.setState((state) => {
            // copy the map rather than modifying state.
            const selected = new Map(state.selected);
            selected.set(id, !selected.get(id)); // toggle
            return {selected};
        });
    };

    _renderItem = (item) => (
        <View style={Styles.viewItem}}>
            <Text style={Styles.textItem>{item.text}</Text>
        </View>
    );

    render() {  
        return (
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                extraData={this.state}
                keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

When I did `animatedView` into the `renderItem` it runs all together and it not what I'm looking for.

Kind of [this way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=3&v=q_jh0dl8iH0) (but without press on the button, it will load automatically)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this is not the best solution but I am using the `delay` property of `Animated.timing()` and it works well for me.

My item component looks like this:

```
export default class CustomItem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            scaleValue: new Animated.Value(0)
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(this.state.scaleValue, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration : 600,
            delay: this.props.index * 350
        }).start();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.state.scaleValue }}>
                { this.props.children }
            </Animated.View>
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the flatlist:

```
...
renderItem(item) {
    return (
        <CustomItem index={ item.index } >
            <Text>{ item.first_name }</Text>
        </CustomItem>
    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            data={data }
            renderItem={ this.renderItem.bind(this) }
        />
    );
}
```

So, every single item will delay **350** milliseconds more than the item before it.

Of course, you can change the `duration` of the animation and the `delay` property and find the perfect animation for you :)

You need to be careful with the number of the items because you can wait too much time to see the last item :)

Comment: really nice solution that works.. but this way when I scroll I see "empty screen" until it take the data time to show (because the delay).

Comment: yes, you are right. The reason is that the list items are loaded, but not visible because of the `opacity` property. What you can do is to change the `opacity` with `minHeight` and `maxHeight`, check this tutorial: https://moduscreate.com/blog/expanding-and-collapsing-elements-using-animations-in-react-native/

Comment: Option 2 that I can suggest you is to remove the `delay` property and to pass the `data` as an empty objecty and with `setTimeout` to push the items into the list one by one.

Comment: sounds like nice way.. to push the items to array in state and then each change in this array will render again?

Comment: yes, that's right. You can follow this tutorial: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-animate-the-items-of-a-react-native-flatlist-32c8cbf7ea3d to set the animation

Comment: Finally founded nice solution :) Thanks

Comment: Thank u man. I searched flatlist animations for a week. This code works perfectly. Really appreciated.

Comment: great solution.can you also update how can i remove single item with animation effect from flatlist..just like when we delete email it disappears

Comment: @Manspof you can limit the scrolling event or disable it until the animation (delay) ends :) But yes, this is one of the disadvantages of this approach :)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Animated.Stagger](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#stagger). Runs Animation parallelly but with successively specified delay.